# SQLite subquery syntax error near "("

Tags: sql, sqlite

So I am trying to perform this query on my database:

```
select 
  count(*) 
from (select 
        userID 
      from users 
      where rating> 1000 
        except (select 
                  userID 
                from users 
                where rating > 1000 
                  except select sellerID from auctions));
```

And am getting this error:
"Error: near line 1: near "(": syntax error"

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using this instead? Is this the logical equivalent?

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  Users
 WHERE Rating > 1000
 AND UserID NOT IN (SELECT SellerID FROM Auctions)
```

Comment: Not quite the logical equivalent (in instead of not in) but thank you for pointing me in the correct direction with the in statement!

Comment: @Msencenb: the `except` indicated (to me) that you wanted to exclude all auction sellers. In any case, glad to hear it helped a bit. Good luck!